# Image Processing library/SDK for Android?

Tags: android, library, java, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there any free library or SDK on Android to perform image processing and basic computer vision techniques, similar to `OpenCV`? Something with active development and not obsolete.

I'm looking for basic features and effects like Saturation or Brightness adjustment, Sharpening,  Sepia effects, etc.

Comment: Looks like OpenCV has [an official Android version](https://opencv.org/android/)?

Comment: I think this is obsolete. There is no maven repo to add.